# Finding EVEN number of times repeating integer in an array where rest of the integers repeat ODD number of times

Tags: algorithm

Given is an array of integers. Each number in the array occurs an ODD number of times, but only 1 number is occurring an EVEN number of times. Find that number.

Below is the solution I read on stackoverflow that does NOT work. I am unable to find the link to that solution and I was wondering if somebody could help me understand why this solution is incorrect unless I am doing something wrong below.

We first XOR all the elements in the array. Lets call it `aWithOutDuplicate` which contains all the odd elements except for duplicate one. We then OR all the elements. Lets call it `aAllUnique`that should contain all the unique elements. XORing `aWithOutDuplicate` and `aAllUnique`should spit out the duplicate element.

```
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,9};
    int aWithOutDuplicate = 0;
    int aAllUnique = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      aWithOutDuplicate ^= arr[i];
      aAllUnique |= arr[i];
    }

   cout << (aWithOutDuplicate ^ aAllUnique);
```

Update:
I wonder if this problem can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) space complexity.

Comment: You are wrong. {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9} are **not** repeated. {4} is repeated once. one is an odd number. Or did you mean: "find numbers that **occur** an even number of times" ?

Comment: I took that example for the sake of simplicity. What I meant when I said repeated is the number of occurrences of that number. With that definition in mind, only 4 occurs even number of times (2 times) and rest odd number of times (1 time in the example).

Comment: I think what wildplasser is saying is that repeating a number would make all the occurances appear next to each other in the collection. I don't think the definition of the word "repeat" requires that, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach does not work because there is no way to differentiate a number that appears an even number of times from one that never appears at all.  Consider this 4-bit example:

```
5:  1 0 1
10: 0 1 0 1
-----------
    1 1 1 1 <- both or and xor.
```

Now, add ANY number (<= 15 since it's 4 bits) to the list twice.  The or will stay the same because all the bits have been switched on and `0xf | x == 0xf` for all 4-bit values of x.  The xor will stay the same because `0xf ^  x ^ x == 0xf` for all values of x.  So a counterexample to your method could be, e.g. `{5, 10, 1, 1}`.

Answer (score 3):

**This O(n), O(1) space solution works *ONLY* if the array elements are in the range [1,n-1] for an array of size 'n'.** [Will work for [0,n-1] with a few tweaks mentioned below]

- Scan the array and do the following

  ```
  for(i=0; i < n; i++) 
    A[A[i]]=A[A[i]]*(-1)
  ```
- All array elements with odd occurrences will have a negative value at the end of the scan. The element with the even number of occurrence will have a positive value.

A few tweaks:
If the array range is from [0,n-1], you can have a special case for '0' where you replace '0' with a special character during the first pass (instead of negation). You will have to revert back the special character back to '0' during the 2nd pass and so on.

Comment: The [1, n-1] restriction is annoying. But this is really clever, and I can't find a bug with it. +1.

Comment: Why it is a constant space? You need the input array in the memory for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the array: a, b, a, b, a, c
So the output should be b.
I'll try to explain why your algorithm is wronng. When you apply OR operation, you assume you will get the unique numbers. Yes, of course, a | a | a == a, but what value will you get by doing the following: a | b | c == ? (Probably all bits will be set to 1s, depending on a,b,c)
It's not the same as doing XOR.

Answer (score 0):

In below code I've found the numbers which are repeating even number of time, following brute force approach without using standard library function map:

```
//! Print integers occurring an even number of times in array a.

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 9, 12, 23, 10, 12, 12, 15, 23, 14, 12, 15 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int b[n], count = 0, c[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[j] == arr[i])
                b[i] = ++count;
        count = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[arr[i]] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (c[arr[i]] == 1)
            continue;
        if (b[i] % 2 == 0)
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        c[arr[i]]++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The description of the approach looks to the point. (I'd like the presentation better if it 1) contained comments what _everything non-obvious_ is there for 2) was indented more conventionally: "global things" (like `main()`) at the left edge, 8 (or 4) spaces per level 3) saved vertical space: no braces where not needed, opening brace _not_ in a line of its own.) Don't habitually `using namespace std;`.

Comment: thanks for your comment.can please advice how to write proper answers on stackoverflow?.as i'm now beginner on this...

Comment: (:You can't possibly know what you are asking for;) Part of that has a prepared answer: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are more detailed ones - let me just plug one [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Rule of thumb: Your post will be read _many_ times - diligence is due in writing (e.g., use a spelling checker, capitalise where called for, spaces _after_ punctuation marks). When comments ask for additional information or clarification, edit your post instead of re-commenting.

Comment: Thanks for your editing...I got an idea about how to write code on stack overflow...and will follow your advice while writing further answers....thanks once again..

Comment: (Just checked and noticed an error: `in array a` should read `in array arr` (or `in array <code>arr</code>`, even). Too bad my IDE doesn't alert me to this, even if it _does_ process comments when renaming. Worse, I didn't invest due diligence …)